# component css / scss is not affecting element class in angular2

Tags: css, angular, sass, parent

I'm working on an angular 4 project and I'm trying to override css in a specific component. My changes also show up after compiling but they are not affecting the element. The element sits in a parent component, but I already tried using :host.

Element:
[image: element]

Generated CSS:

[image: generated css]

Comment: Your selector should indeed be targeting the element in question. Have you ensured that it's not being targeted by a selector with higher specificity? Also, have you tried manually reloading your stylesheet with `CTRL` + `F5`, and refreshing your CSS cache by holding `SHIFT` and clicking the refresh icon?

Comment: yes, I also took a different browser. the .main is from a parent component, but as you can see my custom styles are loaded after the original styles were loaded, so the should be overwritten

Comment: Are you able to use class names instead of Angular attributes? I'd recommend that or maybe even data attributes

Comment: Have you tried using the !important keyword.

Comment: I use classes, the angular attribute is generated. I also used !important.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I found out you can style your children component from its parent. The generated css never match what you want. See the picture.
I solved it by passing a state info(expanded @input attr) to the child component and styling it according to this state value as so:

[Image illustrating my point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7gem.png)

...

Comment: Maybe put your code in here directly rather than in an image

Comment: This approach doesn't work for reusable components. You need to be able to write styles for a reusable component once, not EVERY parent of where you use it.